# iOS Keychain -34018 error bring my app to its knees. How to resolve this issue?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, nsuserdefaults, keychain

At this point I feel like I've read everything on this error. Every stackoverflow post on the topic on and off over the past month. I'm developing around the error, knocking off other issues, and coming back to this one when I have new ideas. I simply cannot resolve it though.

It cannot be consistently recreated, it happens completely at random. Maybe 5% of the time. During that 5%, I am unable to write to the keychain. I've used both SSKeychain (https://github.com/soffes/sskeychain) and UICKeychainStore (https://github.com/kishikawakatsumi/UICKeyChainStore). I get the issue no matter which I use.

Some details:

- I'm storing 3 different keys in the Keychain. 1) User's password token for my server 2) A JSON String representation of my server "User" object and 3) A JSON String representation of IAP content (for when an IAP goes through, but my server fails to deliver the IAP Content just purchased).
- I'm storing them all via the following...

  ```
  UICKeyChainStore *keychain = [UICKeyChainStore keyChainStoreWithService:kKeychainService];
  result = [keychain setString:jsonString forKey:kKeychainUser];
  ```
- Despite other answers, this is NOT just occurring while connected to xcode/debugging. It's also occurring when I'm just using my app on my device, with nothing connected. Preventing my from releasing it.
- I use the same string for `UICKeyChainStore -keyChainStoreWithService`. Then I have 3 unique strings for the 3 things I store. Token, User, and Content.
- I'm calling all of the KeyChain calls on the Main Thread. None are on a background thread.

I'm pretty desperate for a solution. Can I just encrypt these myself, and store them in NSUserDefaults, because I can't rely on the Keychain right now.

Comment: What are the sizes in bytes of items 2 & 3? Just for testing, if the content is a short string does it still fail?

Comment: @zaph Yes I've had it fail with all 3 key's that I'm storing. My token is always the shortest, and I think always about ~22 characters in length. The user JSON string, I just tested the bytes. Typically under 200, but I've tested one over 300 bytes, and it saves to the Keychain fine. Does the Keychain have a 256 limit? I'm guessing no, as this 300+ byte string saves no issue.

Comment: No the Keychain does not have a limit that I am aware of and it is usual to save PKI certs and 4096-bit keys. Just for testing, what about timing? Say if there was a substantial delay between saves, not that I think it is the problem. This is a good candidate to take to the Apple Developer Forums, there are Apple employees there. Also consider using a support incident, you get a couple with the membership. Also the apple-cdsa email list is still active.